# Do the British use words like "batso" or "nutso"?

Tags: spoken-english, slang, colloquial-language, suffixes

Today I encountered the word "batso" and I understood from context it meant "crazy". It interested me because it sounds like an Italian word "pazzo" which means "crazy".

I looked it up and it indeed means "crazy", but has nothing to do with "pazzo". It's just bats + o, there's also nuts + o. I guess these are very American constructions. Am I right? **Do British people use these words and such words?**

**Could you give more example of such words with "o" at the end? Does this o-adding sound right with all adjectives?**

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica I think in this case there is the additional influence of *weirdo* and *psycho*, with *nutso* and *batso* falling somewhere on a spectrum in between.

Comment: @choster: *weirdo* and *psycho* sound relatively "American" to me (as does *wacko* - I should have cited ***fatso*** as a "typically British" usage in the first comment). But personally, my first thought if I saw ***nutso*** or ***batso*** would probably be "non-native speaker trying things out". So I stand by my advice that even though it's still at least *slightly* productive, most non-native speakers would do well to avoid using any variants they haven't seen ***very often*** used by the natives.

Comment: (There's also the question of whether things like ***psycho, typo, nympho, slo-mo, homo*** should be counted as examples of this "suffix", as opposed to being simply "abbreviations".)

Comment: "Fatso" is American as well - a common schoolyard insult among 10-year-olds.

Comment: No, this is not something that sounds right with all adjectives -- did you mean nouns? If it did, you'd see a zillion more examples, not just the few that we've all come up with here.

Comment: *"Today I encountered the word "batso"* Please tell us where you encountered it. Online? in a conversation?  Was it spoken by an American, Australian, Briton, etc?  We need context.  Australians are more prone to adding "o" than Brits.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica In GTA San Andreas ;) So, spoken by an American. In a conversation.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally, no, a British person would be very unlikely to use "batso" or "nutso", and I can't think of anything similar in common useage that *does* end with a 'gratuitous' letter O.

These words have a particularly American feel to them, though there are numerous slang terms that are similar on the surface.

Answer (score 0):

The (generally, diminutive) -o suffix occurs in terms like Hey there, kiddo! and He's completely wacko! And it's still slightly "productive" (e.g. - Paxo for broadcaster Jeremy Paxman). But it's not very common, and I would strongly advise non-native speakers against trying to incorporate it in their own speech. Mostly, it just won't work. It could be seen as highly "affected" in exclamations like No problemo!, or "domain-specific" with variants like journo (journalist).

- [FumbleFingers](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/126/fumblefingers-reinstate-monica?tab=profile)